# Different exceptions occur if execute method from Unit Test and as a Web Service

Tags: apex, webservices

I have a REST class with a method:

```
 @HttpPost
 global satic ReturnedWrapper01 newWrapped01(String name, String uuid) {
    MyCustomObject__c toInsert;
    try {
        toInsert = new MyCustomObject(
          Name = name,
          UUID__c = uuid
        );
        insert toInsert;
      } catch(DmlException de) {
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n --- de: ' + de + '\n');
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n --- de: ' + de.getDmlFieldNames(0) + '\n');
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n --- de: ' + de.getDmlFields(0) + '\n');
        if (de.getMessage().containsIgnoreCase('UUID__c') && de.getMessage().containsIgnoreCase('duplicate') && String.isNotBlank(uuid)) {
          List<MyCustomObject__c> items = [select Id from MyCustomObject__c where UUID__c = :uuid];
          toInsert = items[0];
        } else {
          throw de;
        }
      }
      return toInsert;
  }
```

And here is a trick.
If it is called as Web Service:

> --- de: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: UUID__c duplicates value on record with id: xxxxx00000043ym: []
>
> --- de: ()
>
> --- de: null

If it is called from Unit Test class:

> --- de: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []
>
> --- de: ()
>
> --- de: null

Why? And how to test this? Maybe I should process insertion in another way? How?
UUID__c is text field with uniquness and as External Id.

Comment: Seems like you should be using upsert with UUID as the external Id.

Comment: I don' want to upsert. I want insert. If it was inserted, I do SOQL to retieve this object by UUID. I don't want to update existing object.

Comment: Then it seems like a clearer pattern may be to query first, and if there are no rows, at that point perform the insert.

Comment: I did that. In 50% of Web Service call it is not queried for the first time, then it is not inserted because of duplicate, then I query it for the second time (in catch block) and here it is. So, my team decided to drop that first query at all as it is useless in 50% of the time.